# Android app force closing after splash screen

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I have a splash screen with a timer that runs for 3 seconds. After the 3 seconds it is supposed to auto load another activity called Dashboard. I made a new class that I want to have load after the splash screen called WelcomeSplash. I changed the classes in the splash screen from Dashboard to WelcomeSplash and the app force closes and the logcat says it has a null point exception. Here is the snip of code from the splash class and logcat snip.

```
02-13 23:18:46.826: E/AndroidRuntime(2475): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-13 23:18:46.826: E/AndroidRuntime(2475): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start   
activity ComponentInfo{com.magicbuddy.gamble/com.magicbuddy.gamble.welcomeSplash}:  
java.lang.NullPointerException
02-13 23:18:46.826: E/AndroidRuntime(2475):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
```

Here is the snip of the Splash code

```
    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, welcomeSplash.class));
```

When I change the welcomeSPlash.class to Dashboard.class the app does not force close. Here is the welcomeSplash Activity,

```
public class welcomeSplash extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


Button btnskip;
Button btnplay;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

  btnskip =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
  btnskip.setOnClickListener(this);
  btnplay =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
  btnplay.setOnClickListener(this);


} 

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSkip:
            Intent a = new Intent(welcomeSplash.this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(a);
            break;
        case R.id.btnOk:
            Intent i = new Intent(welcomeSplash.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

THe manifest is copied below too.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.magicbuddy.gamble"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.welcomeSplash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Player"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Menu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Popup"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_popup" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: please show me tag of activity in manifest file

Comment: please add `welcomeSplash` class code with question. probably you forget to initialize View or variable in `welcomeSplash` before using.

Comment: the error seem to you don't declare the welcomsplash  activity in mainfest.xml could you post it with the welcomsplash   class ?

Comment: Post your Timer code for Activity

Comment: remove  `<intent-filter>` from your `welcomeSplash activity` in `manifest.xml`

Comment: i may be problem with the action in welcomesplash activity

Comment: The problem is in the welcomeSplash?

Comment: try cleaning the project and building it again, and also remove this: <action android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard" />

Comment: I removed it and cleaned and I am getting a null point error

Comment: what is your XML for welcomeSplash? And do you have more logcat data?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code from your menifest

```
 <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.magicbuddy.gamble.Dashboard" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
```